Subquery in From Doctrine 2
I have been trying really hard to figure this out by myself but i can't seem to find any solution. So here we go!
I have two entities with income and cost and they are attached to a third entity called Project::class

Invoice::amount() (income)
SupplierInvoice::amount() (cost)

My goal here is to filter out all Projects that have a negative result. And calculate that result.

So i do one request which paginates my projects into sections of 20 where i display the result for each row.
And another where I calculate the complete result and show it in a card. i.e. Result: -10.000$

Here is the SQL which works well as a "native" query. But i can't figure out how to write this one in Doctrine 2.
IMPORTANT!
The "main" request is the one that controls which projects i'm looking into since there are about 8 more filters that are applied in different scenarios. So to my knowledge there isn't any other place in the query where i can write my subquery

PHP Version: 8.1

MySQL Version: 8.0

Doctrine Versions:

"doctrine/orm": "^2.6",
"doctrine/migrations": "^2.3",



SELECT 
    SUM(
        (
            SELECT SUM(i.amount) AS invoice i
            FROM invoice i
            WHERE i.project_id = p.id
        )
    ) AS income,
    SUM(
        (
            SELECT SUM(si.amount) AS supplier_invoice si
            FROM supplier_invoice si
            WHERE si.project_id = p.id
        )
    ) AS cost

FROM project p

WHERE p.id IN (
    SELECT p20.id FROM (
        SELECT
            p10.id,
            SUM(
                (
                    SELECT SUM(i.amount) AS invoice i
                    FROM invoice i
                    WHERE i.project_id = p10.id
                )
            ) AS inner_income,
            SUM(
                (
                    SELECT SUM(si.amount) AS supplier_invoice si
                    FROM supplier_invoice si
                    WHERE si.project_id = p10.id
                )
            ) AS inner_cost
        FROM project p10
        
        GROUP BY p10.id
        HAVING inner_cost > inner_income
    ) p20
);


Here is a simple test to see if i even can write it something like this. It did now work. Error
public function queryBuilderForEconomyNegativeWhatever(?callable $build_callback = null): callable {
    return function(QueryBuilder $qb) use ($build_callback): void {
        $expr = $this->entity_manager->getExpressionBuilder();
        $qb->andWhere(
            $expr->in('pi.id', sprintf('(
                SELECT p20.id FROM (
                    SELECT
                        p10.id
                    FROM %s p10
                    WHERE p10.id > 500
                ) p20
            )', Project::class))
        );
        if ($build_callback !== null) {
            $build_callback($qb);
        }
    };
}

Doctrine \ ORM \ Query \ QueryException
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 1928 near 'FROM ( SELECT p10.id FROM': Error: Subquery is not supported here

I also tried to make User Defined Function in Doctrine 2
Here is my example:
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace KaratenBygg\App\Doctrine\Extensions;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\ArithmeticExpression;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Subselect;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class InSubQuery extends FunctionNode {

    public const NAME = 'insubquery';

    private Subselect $sub_select1;
    private ArithmeticExpression $expr1;
    private ArithmeticExpression $expr2;

    public function parse(Parser $parser): void {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->expr1 = $parser->ArithmeticExpression();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);

        $this->expr2 = $parser->ArithmeticExpression();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->sub_select1 = $parser->Subselect();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker): string {
        // pi.id, p20.id, ( SELECT p10.id FROM project p10 )
        return sprintf('%s IN (SELECT %s FROM (%s))',
            $this->expr1->dispatch($sqlWalker),
            $this->expr2->dispatch($sqlWalker),
            $this->sub_select1->dispatch($sqlWalker),
        );
    }
}


You should try to convert your query to DQL gradually and see what is not working as intended. If there is something causing you some issues, then you could search or ask a question. Just dumping your raw sql query and hoping for someone to actually convert it is not the way SO works.

@DylanKAS i have tried to do it step by step. I have a feeling you didn't read the whole post? You can clearly see that i've tried to solve it my self, and since i'm out of ideas and can't find any solution i came to SO. Best of luck.
